# How to get the data from after matching ids in database?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Hi i am workin on a webapplication where manager assigns work to the employees from grid..

i have database tables like this

```
     ManagerTable
      Customerid
      name
      and some other columns
     EmployeeTable
     empid
      employeeName
     Worktable
      CustomerID
      EmpID
```

Database:

```
Table 1                                               Table 2
CustomerID | CustomerName|CustomerAddress          EmpID |EmpName
---------                                          -------------------
 1 | One    |--|--                                 1 | EmployeeName
 2 | Two                                           2 | EmployeeName
 3 | Three

            Table 3
            Tb1 | Tb2
            ---------
//            1 | 1
//            1 | 2
```

when ever manager assigns check box to a partcualr employee with unique id like(CustomerID,EmployeeID) should be store on a button click in worktable and i have to retriev the data from work table using the IDS stored in the table and show them in grid

when ever a employee logins with his id it should check and get the data assigen to him in a grid  all the employees have same web page

can any one help me with querys and code will be most helpfull...

Comment: i m not geting any idea where to start...

Comment: Then I suggest, you should try some tutorial of web programming and database sql first. http://www.asp.net/get-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i to had a same problem as yours i hpe you are using a template in the grid...giving checkBox some id...for example i had given in my example "Chkselect" id for checkbox...i dnt how ur gona give ur table two...but in my example had bindde table two to dropdown and then on button click every thing runs...

```
           Aspx

           <obout:Column DataField="CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO" HeaderText="CUSTOMER_LOAN_NO"  ReadOnly="true">
       <%-- <TemplateSettings RowEditTemplateControlId="txtCustmLn" RowEditTemplateControlPropertyName="value"/>  --%>    
       <TemplateSettings TemplateId="ChkSelect1" />      
        </obout:Column> 

<obout:GridTemplate ID="ChkSelect1" runat="server" >
        <Template>
        <obout:OboutCheckBox runat="server" ID="Chkselect"  ToolTip="<%# Container.Value %>"  ></obout:OboutCheckBox>
        </Template>
        </obout:GridTemplate>   


    Aspx page behind code


            void grid1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == GridRowType.DataRow && GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState.Count > 0)
    {
        GridDataControlFieldCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
        CheckBox chk = cell.FindControl("Chkselect") as CheckBox;

        GridDataControlFieldCell cellInViewState = GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState[e.Row.RowIndex].Cells[0] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
        CheckBox chkInViewState = cellInViewState.FindControl("Chkselect") as CheckBox;

        if (cell.Value == chkInViewState.ToolTip)
        {
            chk.Checked = chkInViewState.Checked;
        }
    }
}

protected void BtnAssignWork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LoanIds = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState.Count; i++)
    {
        GridDataControlFieldCell cell = GrdCustomerData.RowsInViewState[i].Cells[0] as GridDataControlFieldCell;
        CheckBox chk = cell.FindControl("Chkselect") as CheckBox;

        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoanIds))
               LoanIds += "";

           LoanIds = chk.ToolTip;
                    SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
                    SqlCommand mycomm = new SqlCommand("SP_AssignedWork", myconn);
                    myconn.Open();
                    mycomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    mycomm.Parameters.Add("@LoanID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LoanIds;
                    mycomm.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DDLSelectEmployee.SelectedValue;
                    mycomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    myconn.Close();
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

i hope this helps......